# Ruby simple map object to has not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple problem but I cannot find a solution.
I have a Forum model (active record) with several fields.

I'm creating a class method that return to me an has with one value as key (not the id) and the other as value.

This is my method:

```
Forum.all.map { |f| [f.old_id => f.icon.url(:micro) ]}
```

It returns

```
[[{10=>"/images/fallback/icon_fallback.png"}],
 [{6=>"/images/fallback/icon_fallback.png"}],
 [{18=>"/images/fallback/icon_fallback.png"}]]
```

instead of

```
{10=>"/images/fallback/icon_fallback.png", 6=>"/images/fallback/icon_fallback.png", 18=>"/images/fallback/icon_fallback.png"}
```

What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

in short you can just modify like this, change `square brackets` to `curly brackets`:

```
Forum.all.inject({}) { |r,f| r.merge!(f.old_id => f.icon.url(:micro)) }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It return

`[{10=>"/images/fallback/icon_fallback.png"},
 {6=>"/images/fallback/icon_fallback.png"},
 {18=>"/images/fallback/icon_fallback.png"}]`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `map` returns an array and the square brackets produce arrays containing hashes.

```
res = {}
Forum.all{|f| res[f.old_id] = f.icon.url(:micro) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a minimal change to your code and receive your needed result by using `to_h`:

```
Forum.all.map { |f| [f.old_id,  f.icon.url(:micro)] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `reduce` or `inject` method, or just construct the `Hash` from `Array`s:

```
Hash[Forum.all.map { |f| [f.old_id, f.icon.url(:micro) ]}]
```

for [ruby-2.0](/questions/tagged/ruby-2.0) you can use `#to_h` method:

```
Forum.all.map { |f| [f.old_id, f.icon.url(:micro) ]}.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

use active supports `each_with_object`:

```
Forum.all.each_with_object({}) { |f, h| h[f.old_id] = f.icon.url(:micro) }
```